# Foreign key of ApplicationUser and Controllers

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-identity

I got a similar problem. After making the relations in my model, I got a error in the Controller (Create and Edit). I tried some things, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Model:

```
public class JbsTest{

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public double Duration { get; set; }

public int ProjectId { get; set; }
public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(*db.ApplicationUsers*, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

This line shows the error:

```
ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(*db.ApplicationUsers*, "Id", "Name");
```

ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestProject5.Models.JbsTest> JbsTests { get; set; }
}
```

Error Msg:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Name");` ?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work..